# How do I save a session for a specific time?

Tags: android

I will describe the problem in order:

- passing the username and password to the server,
- I get the session ID.
- This ID is stored on the server for 30 minutes.
- And on the app, I should have it stored for 30 minutes exactly from the moment I received it.

  I have to transmit it for a certain period of time. With SharedPreferences, I can save the ID and pass it, this is understandable.

**What are the mechanisms and ideas for saving a session for half an hour ? What do you use to solve this issue ?**

Guide me . Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Use Alarm Manager for this: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences for saving session too, every new session you will override the old value in SharedPreferences, so there is nothing wrong with using SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should avoid tracking time on the client side because it cannot be completely synced with the server. The best would be to react on invalid sessions. I think here your are talking about oAuth or something similar. You should try to use the session, and if not valid anymore, you refresh it and then try again the call.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try and let you know.